# Passing argument with python file and storing it as variable

Tags: python

I need to pass some argument when running pythonfile.

The argument is a path, `/home/user/`, where it should be stored as list, so I can use it in the code later.

Example: when running file. findfiles.py /home/user/ /home/user2/

I want to pass the list to `glob.glob('path *.txt')`, so it can search for files ending in .txt

This is what I got right now:

```
import glob

test = glob.glob('*.txt')
text1 = "file "
text2 = " has following 2 line inside"
for files in test:
        print text1 + files + text2 
        f = open(files, "r")
        print(f.readline())
        print(f.readline())
```

It searches in current dir after *.txt and list the files and first 2 lines.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: To me it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: Look at the module `argparse` in the Standard Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have several options :

1.use `Argparse`, to read more:
   https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

2.use `sys.argv` which in your simple case seems the simplest :

```
import sys
script_argument = sys.argv[1:]
print script_argument 
# output is : "['/home/user/', '/home/user2/']"
```

just use that according to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thx for tips, but what i used in the end was.

printfiles.py /home/user/ /home/user2/
where the two arguments would be stored in list.

```
import glob, sys, os
list = []
list = sys.argv
    for stuff in list:
    result = glob.glob(os.path.join(stuff, '*.txt'))
    print stuff
```

would return the .txt files it found. 
i could later open them with result.

```
for files in result:
                        print text1 + files + text2 
                        f = open(files, "r")
                        print(f.readline())
```